# Change the size of a bootstrap button in a div

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap buttons in my code. I would like to change certain buttons in a particular div however. The should be smaller

```
 <div class="well">
  <div class="bookmark">

  <% @bookmarks.each do |bookmark| %>
   <p>  
   <%= link_to bookmark.url %>
  #these should be smaller
  <%= link_to "Edit bookmark", edit_topic_bookmark_path(@topic, bookmark), class: "btn btn-danger"  %>
   <%= link_to "Destroy bookmark", [@topic, bookmark], method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger" %>
  </p>

  <%= render partial: 'favorites/favorite', locals: { favorite: @favorite, bookmark: @bookmark } %>
  <% end %>
  </div>

 <%= link_to "New bookmark", new_topic_bookmark_path(@topic), class: 'btn btn-default' %>
</div>
```

I was trying do this adding this to my application.css.scss file

```
.bookmarks btn {
size: 2px;
}
```

But this does not seem to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is this [**size**](http://webdesign.about.com/od/styleproperties/p/size.htm) you speak of? What are you trying to do? Have you tried the various [**Bootstrap Button Options**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-sizes)

Comment: I just want to make the buttons smaller than their default value ...

Comment: ...and there are options for that..see the second link.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   <p>  
   <%= link_to bookmark.url %>
  #these should be smaller
  <%= link_to "Edit bookmark", edit_topic_bookmark_path(@topic, bookmark), class: "btn btn-danger btn-sm"  %>
   <%= link_to "Destroy bookmark", [@topic, bookmark], method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger btn-sm" %>
  </p>
```

You could these classes for sizing buttons:

- `btn-lg`
- `btn-sm`
- `btn-xs`

[bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-sizes)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the bootstrap [button size](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-sizes) classes?

You custom css for the button could be something like.

```
.custom-button {
  font-size:0.8em;
  padding:5px;
}
```

Where you lower the `padding` and `font size` to reduce the size.

Answer (score -1):

I think the quick way is make it important

```html
.bookmarks btn {
size: 2px!important;
}
```